# How to make Jython work with PIG?

Tags: python, jython, apache-pig

I have jython jar and Pig installed on the server. Have Pig jars as well.
Can someone help me out with the proper steps to bundle them so that I can use my Python UDFs ?
Thanks

Comment: What problem do you have? Does it work as in examples?: http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/udf.html#python-udfs

Answer (score 0):

From my short experience in Pig there are two ways of doing this: you can either place the jar in your Pig's lib folder, somewhere about `/usr/share/pig/lib/`, or register the jar using its specific location from grunt (Pig shell), using:

`REGISTER /path/to/your/jar/jython.jar;`

Once available, register your UDF from grunt using:

`REGISTER '/path/to/your/udf/udf.py' USING jython as py_udf;`

And you can use it like this: `py_udf.my_method(*)`

my_method being the name of the python method you created.